# Is there any Scheduler control for Vb.Net?

Tags: vb.net, scheduler

I'm wondering if there is any scheduler control in Vb.Net (MS VS 2005) and if not I hope I can find a free one that I could use on my application.

How can I implement scheduling tasks requirement in my application?

Comment: The question is quite vague.  The Timer class makes a pretty good scheduler.  If you want to use the Windows scheduler then this project will do: http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/  Or google "c# quartz scheduler"

Comment: This can be closed as "seeking recommendations".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Scheduler, you can create user control. In that control just add grid control and add rows and columns as per your requirements.
this is one way. anther way is, use third party controls like Infragistic, Telerik etc.
They provide scheduler controls with lots of additional features.

Comment: Where I could find other third party controls..specially Telerik / Infragestic...and are they free installed and used??...

Comment: sorry there are paid. you can't use without getting licence.

Comment: ok, thank you....I urgently need this and I think I will get a license...Which one you think is better??

Comment: In my application, i have used Infragistic Controls for Scheduler. and its good according to me. and its give lots of features which i need to put it in my application. so according to me Infragistic is better option. just look at its sample.. http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/winforms/winschedule.aspx#Overview

Comment: If you are satisfied then please upvote me so my point will be increase.:)